Float value is getting bigger in length when i use json response in laravel
I am trying to return the json of coordinates, in laravel. the coordinates are float values, i have to use float becuase i have to slightly maniplute the coordinates  otherwise i can return the string coordinates.
I am using cast in model.
protected $casts = [
      'latitude' => 'float',
      'longitude' => 'float',
    ];

Then without manipulating the coordinates and i return the response
return response($response_manager, 200);

$response_manage is array of coordinates.
In my database, its varchar and the values are 48.83004 lat and 2.2904508 lng. But when i get the response its like
 {
  "latitude": 48.83003639999999964629751048050820827484130859375,
  "longitude": 2.29045076000000000107803543869522400200366973876953125,
 }

All i want is same value(in length,in float, without rounding of becuase coordinates are sensitive to location). I have searched about this issues, but i am getting noting on the internet. Please help me in this regard.
I want to manipulate by adding some value like 0.0001 to slightly move the coordinate, but its a next part. I am stuck in beginning.

Try adding ini_set('serialize_precision', '6');

That's how floats work, they are not precise.
The way you can get better accuracy is by multiplying and then dividing.
For example, for co-ordinates "0.000001" and "0.000004", if we were to add those to each other, we'd end up with: "0.0000049999999999999996", which if we were to round to just the first 6 digits, would still be 0.000004.
In order to prevent this from happening, multiply and then divide by a larger number:
(0.000001 * 1000000 + 0.000004 * 1000000) / 1000000

The result being: 0.000005, as we want.
A more detailed explanation on Floating point precision:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
